# Access Date greater than symbol is not working

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

we are using Macro to retrieve data from MS Access using Query. I have used greater than symbol ">" and i have also used "#" symbol to denote time. However, It is not retriving the actual result. It is taking only the current month value. But it is not considering value for the next month values.

Please help us in resolving the issue

```
expiry = "29/06/2016"

expiry = CDate(expiry)


sql = "select sum(quantity) from table1 where symbol = """ & symbol & """ and symbol_type=""TF"""
    sql = sql & " and expiry_date  > #" & expiry & "#;"

  Dim rs As Recordset
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sql)

    If Not rs.EOF Then
        If Not IsNull(rs(0)) Then
            pos_lookup = rs(0)

    end if
' Debug.print sql

select sum(quantity) from table1 where symbol =  "NET" and symbol_type="TF" and expiry_date  > #29/06/2016#;
```

Comment: Have you tried above sql to paste into query designer?

Comment: may be for the next month any of the condition is failing..pls check the query in designer first..whether its retrieving data for next month also

Comment: Add a `Debug.Print sql` and add the output to your question.

Comment: I have used query designer, it is not picking the greater than symbol for date

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the data type of the field. It was "Text". It works now that I changed it to "Date/Time" data type.